# Resample rasters in for loop using arcpy/python

Tags: arcpy

I have a folder of annual raster land cover maps that are 56x56m spatial resolution. I would like to resample them to 30x30m using a for loop in that folder. I think I am making a small error but unsure of what it may be. The function works but is only able to resample and save one file then it stops.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Documents\rasters"
outFolder = r"C:\Users\Documents\new_rasters"

rasterList = arcpy.ListDatasets("*","Raster")    
for inRaster in rasterList: 
    outName = os.path.join(outFolder,str(inRaster))
    outResampled = arcpy.Resample_management(inRaster, outName, "30",  "NEAREST")
    outResampled.save(outName)
```

Comment: I'd first check to make sure that 'rasterList' is containing everything you think it is.  Put a print statement after it and confirm what ListDatasets is returning.

Comment: The list variable contains all the raster names I want to manipulation

Comment: Wouldn't running the code that you have presented thrown an error in the last line?

Comment: Cross-posted as http://stackoverflow.com/q/39647137/820534

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made the below changes to your code and just ran it on a folder of rasters and it worked.  Give it a try.

```
for inRaster in rasterList:
    print inRaster # just to view progress
    outName = os.path.join(outFolder,str(inRaster))
    arcpy.Resample_management(inRaster, outName, "30",  "NEAREST")
```

The second argument in Resample_management is already telling it where to save the output.

Comment: +1 nice catch - I didn't notice the `outResampled.save()` in the question